# Is there a way to get Splunk Data to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, splunk, looker-studio

I have some app data which is currently stored in Splunk. But i am looking for a way where I can input the Splunk data directly to BigQuery. My target is to analyze the app data on BigQuery and perhaps create Data Studio dashboards based on the BigQuery.
I know there are a lot of third party connectors that can help me with this, but I am looking for a solution where I can use features from Splunk or BigQuery to conncet both of them together and not rely on third party connectors.

Comment: I expect most of the third-party connectors merely utilize the REST API on either end to export from Splunk and import into GBQ, in addition to whatever ETL you might do in the interim. To my knowledge, there's no native connector between the two, so either you'd have to write the program yourself (not difficult - I've done it in less than a day) or use an existing third-party tool.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer, could you share some resources that would guide me initially to develop a custom program?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment indicating that you're interested in resources to egress data from Splunk into BigQuery with custom software, I would suggest using either tool's REST API on either side.

You don't indicate whether this is a one-time or a recurring asking - that may impact where you want the software to run that performs this operation. If it's a one-time thing and you've got a fair internet connection yourself, you may just want to write a console application from your own machine to perform the migration. If it's a recurring operation, you might instead look at any of the various "serverless" hosting options out there (e.g. [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/#overview), [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/), or [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)). In addition to development experience, note that you may have to pay an egress bandwidth cost for each on top of normal service charges.

Beyond that, you need to decide whether it makes more sense to do a [bulk export](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.2.6/Search/Exportdatausingdumpcommand) from Splunk out to some external file that you load into Google Drive and then [import into Big Query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/batch-loading-data). But maybe it makes more sense to download the records as paged data via HTTPS so you can perform some ETL operation on top of it (e.g. replace nulls with empty strings, update Datetime types to match Google's [exacting standards](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#details_of_loading_json_data), etc.). If you go this route, it looks as though this is the [documentation](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.2.6/Search/ExportdatausingRESTAPI) you'd use from Splunk and you can either use Google's newer, and higher-performance [Storage Write API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api) to receive the data or their [legacy streaming API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability) to ingest into BigQuery. Either option supports SDKs across varied languages (e.g. C#, Go, Ruby, Node.js, Python, etc.), though only the legacy streaming API supports plain HTTP REST calls.

Beyond that, don't forget your OAuth2 concerns to authenticate on either side of the operation, though this is typically abstracted away by the various SDKs offered by either party, and less of something you'd have to deal with the ins and outs of.